# Use of AND operator in VB.Net Case statement

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm making a rock, paper, scissors game in VB. I'm looking for a way to make the following work:

```
Select Case userInput
       Case = "rock" And computerOutput = "scissors"
                Console.WriteLine("You win! You picked " & userInput & ", and the computer picked " & computerOutput & "! Rock beats Scissors, hit enter to continue...")
                Console.ReadLine()
                userScore = userScore + 1
```

userInput and computerInput is always either rock, paper or scissors.

But when I try it I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "rock" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.'
```

I'm newish to VB so not really sure what to do.

Comment: We would need to see more of your code to understand your question.

Comment: This is not how to write a Select Case Statement.  You should watch [Excel VBA Introduction Part 14 - Select Case Statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvnIRr30Mus&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=15)

Comment: I guess you are using vb.net? Please provide few more lines of code before and after the line `Case = "rock" And computerOutput = "scissors"`

Comment: I'll edit the post to add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this to write `SELECT CASE` statement :

```
Select [ Case ] testexpression  
    [ Case expressionlist  
        [ statements ] ]  
    [ Case Else  
        [ elsestatements ] ]  
End Select
```

For your code, you can try like this :

```
Select Case userInput
   Case "rock"
        if computerOutput = "scissors" then
            Console.WriteLine("You win! You picked " & userInput & ", and the computer picked " & computerOutput & "! Rock beats Scissors, hit enter to continue...")
            Console.ReadLine()
            userScore = userScore + 1
        end if
```

Comment: Pleased to hear that your problem is sorted out. Please also mark the answer as useful(upvote) also.

Answer (score 1):

The error code tells you it all. You are converting a string type into a boolean type. Rather than doing that, you should use an IF statement to *do stuff* based on what the string results in. For example:

```
Select Case userInput
Case "rock"
    if computerOutput = "scissors" then
    Console.WriteLine("You win! You picked " & userInput & ", and the 
    computer picked " & computerOutput & "! Rock beats Scissors, hit enter 
    to continue...")
    Console.ReadLine()
    userScore = userScore + 1
    end if
```

But I fail to see what is throwing back this error. Please post all of your code.