# How can I use Select Case and the AND function together in Access VBA coding?

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is what I have written:

```
Private Sub CboBusinessID_Click()
    Select Case CboBusinessID
        Case Is = 1, 4, 5, 9, 20, 23, 28, 31, 32, 34 And Me.TxtPEPCatID = "Politically Exposed Foreign Person"
            [BusAns] = "5"
        Case 1, 4, 5, 9, 20, 23, 28, 31, 32, 34 And Me.TxtPEPCatID = "Politically Exposed Domestic Person"
            [BusAns] = "3"
        Case Else
            [BusAns] = "1"
    End Select
End Sub
```

What I am attempting to do is return a number value in the [BusAns] field of "5" when [CboBusinessID] field is any of the values listed (1, 4, 5, etc.) and the [TxtPEPCatID] field is equal to "Politically Exposed Foreign Person", but have it change to "3" when the field is equal to "Politically Exposed Domestic Person".  Right now it is returning a value of "5" only based on the value in the [CboBusinessID].

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931302/use-of-and-operator-in-vb-net-case-statement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of AND operator in VB.Net Case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931302/use-of-and-operator-in-vb-net-case-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```vb
Private Sub CboBusinessID_Click()

    [BusAns] = "1"
    Select Case CboBusinessID
        Case 1, 4, 5, 9, 20, 23, 28, 31, 32, 34
            If Me.TxtPEPCatID = "Politically Exposed Foreign Person" Then
                [BusAns] = "5"
            ElseIf Me.TxtPEPCatID = "Politically Exposed Domestic Person" Then
                [BusAns] = "3"
            End If
    End Select

End Sub
```